# merging 3 functions into one

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have 3 functions. How do I merge them into one?
I have the list of table names in the function 3. The function 2 has node name that corresponds to that table and the function 1 has number of columns in each of the tables.
I will prefer one function with all 3 input values while using the required ones only depending upon the clue passed by the function input.

```
function_1()
{
while read tbl col_num
do
  mysql test -e"call mysql.createtable('$tbl', $col_num);"    
done << mytbl_list
test.authadv 45
test.fee 29
test.finadv 54
mytbl_list
}

# match tables names with the respective nodes

function_2()
{
while read tbl tag
do
  php -e xmlread_new.php $filename $tbl $tag 
done << heredc
test.authadv AUTHADV
test.fee FEE
test.finadv FINADV
heredc
}


# export data to excel. Change the table names as required

function_3()
{
while read tbl_name
do
  mysql --table -e"select * from $tbl_name" > $report_name.txt
done << tbl_heredoc
test.authadv
test.fee
test.finadv
tbl_heredoc
}
```

Comment: In other words, I do not want to write "test.authadv" three times if it is possible to write only once :)

Comment: Please give a before and **after** example that someone who doesn't do your job all day will understand ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use arrays to store your table names and attributes. Create a fourth function to read and store your table names, etc., into those arrays. Then the other three functions can access those arrays.

```
read_tables ()
{
    counter=0
    while read -r tbl col_num tag
    do
        tables[counter]=$tbl
        col_nums[counter]=$col_num
        tags[counter]=$tag
        ((counter++))
    done << 'TABLES'
        test.authadv 45 AUTHADV
        test.fee     29 FEE
        test.finadv  54 FINADV
TABLES
}

create_tables ()
{
    for ((i=0; i<counter; i++))
    do
        mysql test -e"call mysql.createtable('${tables[i]}', ${col_nums[i]});"    
    done
}

# match tables names with the respective nodes

match_tags ()
{
    for ((i=0; i<counter; i++))
    do
        php -e xmlread_new.php "$filename" "${tables[i]}" "${tags[i]}"
    done
}


# export data to excel. Change the table names as required

export_excel ()
{
    for ((i=0; i<counter; i++))
    do
        mysql --table -e"select * from ${tables[i]}" > "$report_name.txt"
    done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see how the functions depend on each other. However, it is supposed to be good style to better have more and smaller functions instead of one big one.

Keywords: Separation of concerns, one tool for one job.

If you have smaller functions, it's easier to reason about them. It is easier to test them. It is easier to find a place to reuse one of them.

Comment: The functions are not dependant on each other. The inputs are common across all functions and I do not want to change the table names at 3 different places :)

Comment: function3 doesn't call function2 or ~1, nor the other way round. There is no other function (statement), calling these functions. Which table names don't you want to change, $tbl?